# How can i use two different scope "this" in one function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i need to get the inner text of a given element through a Jquery event, and then set this text into a member of my class e.g.

```
myClass = function ()
{
    this.index = 0;

    this.onNavElementClick = function ()
    {
        this.index = parseInt(this.text());
    }

    this.myMain = function ()
    {
        $("nav#wow-so-much-inspiration").on("click", "a", this.onNavElementClick);
    }
}

myObject = new myClass();
myObject.myMain();
```

HTML:

```
<nav id="wow-so-much-inspiration">
    <a href="#">1</a>
    <a href="#">2</a>
    <a href="#">3</a>
</nav>
```

But this won't work because of the two different scopes inside the `onNavElementClick()` function... And i don't like the idea of doing `_this = this`, i'm pretty sure there is a right way to do that without doing MacGyver coding.

Comment: jQuery events also pass an event parameter to the callback. It has a property `target`, which is a reference of the element, that emitted the event.

Comment: wow so much inspiration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery event handlers also take the event object (including the `target` on which the event was triggered) as a first argument. Then you can use `$.proxy` to have your event handler bound to the outer `this`.

Something like this:

```
this.onNavElementClick = $.proxy(function (e)
{
    this.index = parseInt($(e.target).text());
}, this);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of the `bind` method, but I *believe* this has been proven to have minor performance implications.

Example - which is essentially what the $.proxy answer does.

```
var myClass = function ()
{
    this.index = 0;

    this.onNavElementClick = (function (event) {
        this.index = parseInt( $(event.target).text() );
    }).bind(this);

    this.myMain = function ()
    {
        $("nav#wow-so-much-inspiration").on("click", "a", this.onNavElementClick);
    };
}

var myObject = new myClass();
myObject.myMain();
```

Another option is to use `call` or `apply` with a simple wrapper function.

```
var myClass = function ()
{
    this.index = 0;

    this.onNavElementClick = function (event)
    {
        this.index = parseInt( $(event.target).text() );
    };

    this.myMain = function ()
    {
        var self = this;
        $("nav#wow-so-much-inspiration").on("click", "a", function (event) {
            self.onNavElementClick.call(self, event);
        });
    };
}

var myObject = new myClass();
myObject.myMain();
```

Answer (score 0):

Define onNavElementClick as a var within the my class constructor and reuse the function as needed.

```
var onNavElementClick = function(){...};
```